# WiFi connection limited access occurs very often

Tags: wireless-networking

I have been using my router for more than 3 years, and lately my WiFi networks started to act strange. I am not sure if it's Windows or router trouble.

Very often I am being disconnected from everything, and pages does not load `ERR_DOMAIN_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` for pages with domains, but also when I type IP: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I tried changing channel of my WiFi network after analyzing other networks in InSSIDer. 
It still didn't fix the problem.

When there is `limited access` I tried pinging my router:
[image: first ping]

However after a moment it started to reply, the latency was very high though:
[image: second ping]

And it started being okay after that: 
[image: third ping]

The same situation happens very often(5-30min)

What do you suspect, router or my windows/network card issue?

Comment: What `WiFi Adapter` do you use?  What router do you use?  How long of a window in time have you had this problem?

Comment: This problem started to happening yesterday night, after I left download to finish. Its built-in wireless card: `Atheros AR9285`. Everything has been working okay for 3 years.

Comment: I assume you don't have access to another WiFi adapter?

Comment: Nope, I just know that two other devices connected via cable work well.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the settings on the router? Have you added any **new** wireless devices recently to your network

Comment: No, I didn't add anything recently. Another weird fact I discovered: I was away for 20 minutes, when I got back I saw the connectivity icon with yellow triangle, after I clicked on it, the network started recovering. I tried restarting computer, and I wasn't changing any Windows settings lately. Maybe it's just my delusion, but it's weird.